# Why is foreach better than get for Scala Options?

Tags: scala, scala-option

Why using `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap` etc. are considered better than using `get` for Scala Options? If I use`isEmpty` I can call `get` safely.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Well, it kind of comes back to "tell, don't ask". Consider these two lines:

```
if (opt.isDefined) println(opt.get)
// versus
opt foreach println
```

In the first case, you are looking inside `opt` and then reacting depending on what you see. In the second case you are just telling `opt` what you want done, and let it deal with it.

The first case knows too much about `Option`, replicates logic internal to it, is fragile and prone to errors (it can result in run-time errors, instead of compile-time errors, if written incorrectly).

Add to that, it is not composable. If you have three options, a single for comprehension takes care of them:

```
for {
  op1 <- opt1
  op2 <- opt2
  op3 <- opt3
} println(op1+op2+op3)
```

With `if`, things start to get messy fast.

Answer (score 22):

One nice reason to use `foreach` is parsing something with nested options. If you have something like

```
val nestedOption = Some(Some(Some(1)))
for {
  opt1 <- nestedOption
  opt2 <- opt1
  opt3 <- opt2
} println(opt3)
```

The console prints `1`. If you extend this to a case where you have a class that optionally stores a reference to something, which in turn stores another reference, for comprehensions allow you to avoid a giant "pyramid" of None/Some checking.

Answer (score 19):

There are already excellent answers to the actual question, but for more `Option`-foo you should definitely check out [Tony Morris' Option Cheat Sheet](https://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: Found this page here instead of the link above: http://tmorris.net/posts/2008-01-16-scalaoption-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: that cheat sheet is fantastic

Answer (score 6):

The reason it's more useful to apply things like `map`, `foreach`, and `flatMap` directly to the `Option` instead of using `get` and then performing the function is that it works on either `Some` *or* `None` and you don't have to do special checks to make sure the value is there.

```
val x: Option[Int] = foo()
val y = x.map(_+1) // works fine for None
val z = x.get + 1  // doesn't work if x is None
```

The result for `y` here is an `Option[Int]`, which is desirable since if `x` is optional, then `y` might be undetermined as well.  Since `get` doesn't work on `None`, you'd have to do a bunch of extra work to make sure you didn't get any errors; extra work that is done for you by `map`.

Comment: Yes, I mean `get`. I am fixing the post.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply:

- If you need to do something (a procedure when you don't need to capture the return value of each invocation) only if the option is defined (i.e. is a `Some`): use `foreach` (if you care about the results of each invocation, use `map`)
- If you need to do something if the option defined and something else if it's not: use `isDefined` in an if statement
- If you need the value if the option is a `Some`, or a default value if it is a `None`: use `getOrElse`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to perform  our Operations with   `get` is more imperative style where u need to tel *what to do and how to do* . In other words , we are dictating things and  digging more into the `Options` internals. Where as  `map,flatmap`  are more functional way of doing things where we are say *what to do but not how to do*.