# Examples of using some Scala Option methods

Tags: scala, scala-option

I have read the [blog post](https://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/) recommended me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819373/why-is-foreach-better-than-get-for-scala-options). Now I wonder what some those methods are useful for. Can you show examples of using `forall` (as opposed to `foreach`) and `toList` of `Option`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have one practical example of `toList` method. You can find it in [scaldi](https://github.com/OlegIlyenko/scaldi) (my Scala dependency injection framework) in [Module.scala](https://github.com/OlegIlyenko/scaldi/blob/f3697ecaa5d6e96c5486db024efca2d3cdb04a65/src/main/scala/scaldi/Module.scala) at line 72:

https://github.com/OlegIlyenko/scaldi/blob/f3697ecaa5d6e96c5486db024efca2d3cdb04a65/src/main/scala/scaldi/Module.scala#L72

In this context `getBindings` method can return either `Nil` or `List` with only one element. I can retrieve it as `Option` with `discoverBinding`. I find it convenient to be able to convert `Option` to `List` (that either empty or has one element) with `toList` method.

Comment: @AdamFraser: Sorry for this. I updated the link, and also used specific commit tree instead of master.

Answer (score 27):

- `map`: Allows you to transform a value "inside" an `Option`, as you probably already know for `List`s. This operation makes `Option` a functor (you can say "endofunctor" if you want to scare your colleagues)
- `flatMap`: `Option` is actually a monad, and `flatMap` makes it one (together with something like a constuctor for a single value). This method can be used if you have a function which turns a value into an `Option`, but the value you have is already "wrapped" in an `Option`, so `flatMap` saves you the unwrapping before applying the function. E.g. if you have an `Option[Map[K,V]]`, you can write `mapOption.flatMap(_.get(key))`. If you would use a simple `map` here, you would get an `Option[Option[V]]`, but with `flatMap` you get an `Option[V]`. This method is cooler than you might think, as it allows to chain functions together in a very flexible way (which is one reason why Haskell *loves* monads).
- `flatten`: If you have a value of type `Option[Option[T]]`, `flatten` turns it into an `Option[T]`. It is the same as `flatMap(identity(_))`.
- `orElse`: If you have several alternatives wrapped in `Option`s, and you want the first one that holds actually a value, you can chain these alternatives with `orElse`: `steakOption.orElse(hamburgerOption).orElse(saladOption)`
- `getOrElse`: Get the value out of the `Option`, but specify a default value if it is empty, e.g. `nameOption.getOrElse("unknown")`.
- `foreach`: Do something with the value inside, if it exists.
- `isDefined`, `isEmpty`: Determine if this `Option` holds a value.
- `forall`, `exists`: Tests if a given predicate holds for the value. `forall` is the same as `option.map(test(_)).getOrElse(true)`, `exists` is the same, just with `false` as default.
- `toList`: Surprise, it converts the `Option` to a `List`.

Answer (score 11):

Many of the methods on Option may be there more for the sake of uniformity (with collections) rather than for their usefulness, as they are all very small functions and so do not spare much effort, yet they serve a purpose, and their meanings are clear once you are familiar with the collection framework (as is often said, Option is like a list which cannot have more than one element).

forall checks a property of the value inside an option. If there is no value, the check pass. For example, if in a car rental, you are allowed one `additionalDriver: Option[Person]`, you can do

```
additionalDriver.forall(_.hasDrivingLicense)
```

exactly the same thing that you would do if several additional drivers were allowed and you had a list.

toList may be a useful conversion. Suppose you have options: List[Option[T]], and you want to get a List[T], with the values of all of the options that are Some. you can do

```
for(option <- options; value in option.toList) yield value
```

(or better `options.flatMap(_.toList)`)